Accessing Smart Card Certificates in a Blazor WebAssembly App for Client-Side PDF Signing
I am developing a Blazor WebAssembly application that requires digitally signing PDF files on the client side. The signing process involves a certificate stored on a smart card, which can be accessed when the card is plugged into the PC.
The smart card requires specific middleware to be installed on the client machine to facilitate access to the certificate. My question is:
Is it possible to access the certificates on the smart card directly from a Blazor WebAssembly app?
If so, what steps do I need to take to set up the middleware and access the certificates securely?
Are there any libraries or APIs that can help with this process, especially for interacting with the smart card and signing the PDF documents?
Currently, I have implemented SignalR to communicate through a Hub with a server using the signLib library, which works well for signing PDF documents. However, the signing process and certificate access are handled on the server side, and I need to move this functionality to the client side.
